# Blow up at an ordinary double point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, complex-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a complex complete intersection surface with only ordinary double point singularities. Let $o$ be such an ordinary double point.

Let $\tilde{X}$ be the strict transform of $X$ with respect to the blow up of $\mathbb{C}^n$ at $o$. My question is, how does $\tilde{X}$ look like?

I know that locally at $o$, the strict transform should look like a a smooth rational curve with self-intersection $−2$, and should look like $X$ far away from $o$. (This can be formalized by taking a small neighborhood of $o$). But how do these two parts "glue"?

Comment: This is incorrect --- locally at $o$ the strict transform looks like a neighborhood of a smooth rational curve with self-intersection $-2$.

Comment: @Sasha why? Locally at $o$, $X$ would be a sum of squares by Morse's lemma.

Comment: It is a sum of **three** squares.

Comment: @Sasha You are right. I corrected the question accordingly. Thanks!